# How can a controller observe its own value?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble getting my ApplicationController to observe one of its values. A view is calling a function on the controller, which changes its `selectedIds` property. Another method on the controller observes this:

```
hi: function() {
  console.log('hi');
}.observes('selectedIds')
```

but only is called the first time. Is this the correct way to specify an observer?

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ojigev/1/edit). Open the console + click on the links, you'll see that the controller property changes but `hi` is only triggered once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is more with observing Ember arrays rather than observing a controller's own value.

Observers are observing properties. So when you just push something into the array, the property (that array) does not change.

Firstly, you need to use Ember's pushObject method to treat the elements in the array like Ember Objects:

```
allIds.pushObject(id); // not allIds.push(id)
```

Then the observer should observe every element of the array using @each, rather than observing the array itself.

```
hi: function() {
    console.log('hi');
}.observes('selectedIds.@each')
```

Updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/aqagij/2/edit

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks both of you! one follow-up... is Ember aware of `.pushObject` anywhere I use it? For example, `this.get('controller.selectedIds').pushObject(4)`?

Comment: also: Ember changes primitive javascript arrays?

Comment: Bah both beat me, see See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html and you can manually trigger the change with `this.notifyPropertyChange('selectedIds')` if using plain arrays.

Comment: Answer to my second question: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#sts=pushObject

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to specify an observer?

No, use `.observes('selectedIds.@each') instead.

With just .observes('selectedIds') observer is only going to get called when selectedIds changes. So the first time you click a link, selectedIds changes from null to an array with one element and the observer fires.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the selectedIds is a plain array of plain objects. Ember doesn't know that an item was added. The two options are, to either  manually alert that a change occurred after you do any adds or removes, or let Ember 'automatically' know by using its array object.

Or manually notify Ember and just observe the array as a whole:

```
 this.notifyPropertyChange('selectedIds')
 .observes('selectedIds')
```

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

Comment: Both of the above beat me, added just to show an alternative of manually triggering a generic notifyPropertyChange for completeness